# Is null character supposed to cause stack smashing?

Tags: c, buffer

I'm testing when stack smashing is detected, and I noticed I don't get stack smashing is detected when I write a null character after a char buffer.

In this example, I write characters into a char buffer, and then write the null character at the end (with f-stack-protector):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buf[8];
  char c;

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) buf[i] = c;
  buf[i] = '\0';
  printf("string = [%s]\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

I noticed that writing 9 characters will give me `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated` as expected, but writing 8 characters does not. If I input 8 characters in this example, wouldn't the null character be written after the buffer and smash the stack?

I tried replacing the null character to writing some other character like 'A' and I will also get stack smashing detected. Is the null character special in this regard, or is this behaviour unexpected?

Comment: Count the number of variable `i` declarations you have...

Comment: Your compiler might show some warning like "use of variable i without assigning a value first" when you try to `buf[i] = '\0';`. If not, turn up compiler warnings. For GCC or Clang you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Your edit changed the code significantly. You are supposed to show the exact code that actually causes your issue. Is the old or the new version showing the issue? Was the edit intented to show the fix or to show the real code with the problem?

Comment: Please don't "fix" code in your questions. That make comments, and worse, answers possibly worthless, as well as the question itself as the code no longer have the problem being asked about. Remember that this site isn't only to help you right now, but also to help other users with the same or a similar problem.

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, the current version is relevant to the question

Comment: Then please keep in mind for future questions that you should copy&paste the real code into the question instead of retyping something somehow similar to your code. That avoids typos introducing more errors not related to your main iss.e

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have to disagree here. The edit is fine. Invalidating comments by doing edits is fine (actually we often makes comments to make OP do an edit that will invalidate our comment). Edits shall **not** invalidate an answer but in this case it doesn't. So all is good

Comment: @jayer Is the behavior of your program still the same as described in the question? Setting the null-terminator out of bounds still doesn't create the expected "stack smashing"?

Comment: Writing out of bounds to an array on the stack is not (always) the same as "stack smashing". It depends on the actual layout/use of the stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, it still doesn't cause stack smashing. Also, apologies for making a mistake on the code initially!

Comment: You seem to hit `c` with your out of bounds access. As this is still in the valid stack frame, it is probably not possible to be detected.

Comment: @Gerhardh This makes sense, but then I tried changing `buf[i] = '\0'` in the code to some other character e.g. `buf[i] = 'a'`, and I get the expected stack smashing when I input 8 characters

Comment: `c` should be of type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are aware that writing to the array out of bounds is undefined behavior. Consequently, what happens when executing your code depends on the system being used.

Further, the `-fstack-protector` option is not defined by the C standard so the standard can't tell exactly what it does. You need to read the documentation for your specific compiler to see if the details are explained. Again the point is... what happens when executing your code depends on the system being used.

A way to detect stack smashing is to put some kind of magic pattern on the current stack frame and just before the function returns, it's checked that the magic pattern is still there. In other words - if the pattern has changed we have "stack smashing"; otherwise all is good.

So for fun I took your code and ran it - with a small modification - on my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buf[8];
  char c;

  // NOTICE
  printf("buf is at: %p\n", (void*)buf);
  printf("c   is at: %p\n", (void*)&c);

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) buf[i] = c;

  // NOTICE
  if (i == 8 && buf[i] == '\0') puts("Already NUL");
    
  buf[i] = '\0';
  printf("string = [%s]\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

And I gave the input "12345678" and got:

```
buf is at: 0x7ffe562b8450
c   is at: 0x7ffe562b844b
Enter a string: 12345678
Already NUL
string = [12345678]
```

Two things to notice:

1. the variable `c` is located at a lower address than `buf` so writing after `buf` will not end up in `c`
2. It printed "Already NUL" so the byte just after `buf` already contained the value that the program writes when doing `buf[i] = '\0';` so the write does **not** change any value. So the code detecting "stack smashing" will not see any change of stack data.

Once again I changed your code so that it write an A instead of a NUL in case there already is a NUL just after `buf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buf[8];
  char c;

  printf("buf is at: %p\n", (void*)buf);
  printf("c   is at: %p\n", (void*)&c);

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) buf[i] = c;

  if (i == 8 && buf[i] == '\0')
  {
    puts("Already NUL");
    buf[i] = 'A';
  }
  else
  {
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("string = [%s]\n", buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and I got:

```
buf is at: 0x7fffa405e070
c   is at: 0x7fffa405e06b
Enter a string: 12345678
Already NUL
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

So on my system it seems that writing a NUL just after `buf` will not be detected simply because that part of the stack already contained a NUL. So the write didn't change anything.

But just to repeat... all this depends on the system being used (due to undefined behavior) and depends on how the "stack smashing" is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer of 8 has only room for 7 characters + 1 null terminator. Therefore you invoke undefined behavior if you attempt to write beyond that. The null character isn't special, undefined behavior means that anything can happen, including "the program seems to work fine". See [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

As a side note, any variable storing the result from `getchar()` should be declared as `int`. This is because `getchar()` may return `EOF`, which is an `int` not a `char`. And yes, it is incredibly stupid to standardize a function named `getchar()` and have it return an `int`, not a `char`. The whole of `stdio.h` is filled with library design faults and it should therefore be avoided in production-quality code.

Answer (score 0):

Exception with memory are unpredictable, so don't think why they didn't happen.

An error may occur if an attempt is made to access a location outside of the memory range, but it may not be.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).